# How to calculate the camera position, so that a specified 3D model fills the viewport?

Tags: math, 3d, xna

How to calculate the camera position, so that a specified 3D model fills the viewport? The camera direction should be maintained. Camera is a perspective camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute a bounding sphere around your model. Say the radius is r and the center is c. Place the camera target point at the center of the sphere. If your camera has field-of-view a, you can compute the required distance L from the camera to the camera target.

```
tan(a/2) = r/L
```

Which gives

```
L = r/tan(a/2)
```

If the camera view direction was v to begin with the new camera position will be

```
p = c - normalize(v)*L
```

This will keep the direction of the camera and ensure the whole model is visible.

Note that if your viewport is rectangular and not square, you must use the F.O.V. from the shorter side of the viewport.